# Why netty Promise listeners signature future return type is <? super V>

Tags: java, generics, promise, netty

The signature of method `addListener` for `io.netty.util.concurrent.Promise<V>`
is

`Promise<V> addListener(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>> listener)`

Please explain why the argument is not of type `GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? extends V>>`
because it seems to make sense that the result of promise should be `V` or its subclasses but not its superclasses.

But why the return type of Future is `<? super V>` ?

Answer (score 4):

What we need here is something which can listen to `V` at least. It *may* be able to listen to more, but it would not be enough if it would only be able to listen to a subclass of `V`.

For example, for a class chain `Animal` -> `Mammal` -> `Dog`, if I'd like to have a Listener for a `Mammal`, a Listener for an `Animal` would be fine, but a Listener for a `Dog` wouldn't, because my `Mammal` could as well be a `Cat`.